Solving variables in symbolic unitary to get a desired real-valued unitary using qiskit or qympy, qiskit-symb/pytket
I am trying to decompose a 4x4 unitary into 2 qubit circuit using U3 and CNOT gates but the circuit implementation qiskit gives me is not optimized. So I started looking at qiskit-symb and qympy to see if I can design a parameterized circuit and solve the circuit unitary parameters to get my desired unitary.
I am not sure how to equate the parameterized (symbolic) unitary to the unitary I want by solving/evaluating these parameters. Any guidance would be helpful
Thanks!

Hi, welcome to QCSE. Is the unitary you want to synthesise a circuit for symbolic or numeric? Can you share the matrix and what you've attempted so far? It is known that any two qubit unitary can be implemented with at most 3 CNOT gates. See this paper -> https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0308006 .

In pytket you can pass a 4x4 numpy array representing your (numeric) unitary to Unitary2qBox and then decompose the box in terms of {U3, CNOT} for an optimial circuit. I can expand on this in an answer if thats helpful.

Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please provide more detail, for example a circuit you are trying to decompose and used Qiskit code.

@Callum,
Hey, thanks for the pytket reference, I will check it out. Yes, I am actually looking for something like 'Unitary2qBox'. I found a similar method in Qiskit called 'transpile' that acts on a given unitary to spit out a circuit. But the circuit I'm getting is not optimal. So I am will check out your suggestion.
